# Get all files from Assets Windows Store Application

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am developing a Windows Store application and have about 20 images in the Assets/Backgrounds folder.

**How can I get those files from C#?**

I only need the file path, for example I need to create a List of strings object with file path. For example the list can be in the format of

```
List<string> files = new List<string> {"Assets/Backgrounds/file1.jpg", 
     "Assets/Backgrounds/file2.jpg", ...};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This contains all the files in your application package

```
   ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap
```

Use Linq to filter those you need

Answer (score 2):

First you need To know the Path of your Contents

```
string ImagesFile = @"Assets/Backgrounds/file1.jpg";
```

Then you Can Access The file like This:

```
StorageFolder InstallationFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        StorageFile file = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync(ImagesFile);
```